# Where to store data to be used by all processes?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, heap-memory

I am trying several projects in editing a Linux kernel.

One of the projects is to write a system call function that will receive a name of a program and not allow that program to be run through execv (note, several programs can be blocked - we need a list of blocked programs).

I have figured out what to do for most of the exercise. For example, one challenge is to log all attempts of a certain process to execute any of the blocked programs - I decided to store this in the heap of the process using kmalloc().

However, I am debating where to store the "list of blocked programs" - no matter which process is running, when in execv we must have access to this list. Would it make sense then to store this list inside the heap of the init process or is there some "general" memory location that is shared between all processes (never heard of one before but I was wondering if there might be one).

If the answer is indeed inside the heap of init, how do I allocate memory there from whichever process is currently running?

Comment: kmalloc() does not allocate heap memory in a process. You're running in the kernel, everything in the kernel has access to all parts of memory. It wouldn't be uncommon for kernel code to simply use a global variable for such a purpose, tough get locking arounf it right.

Comment: @nos So where does it allocate memory? What happens when a process exits, does it delete anything?

Comment: `kmalloc()` allocates memory from the kernel's memory allocator. It remains allocated until you pass it to `kfree()`. The memory block has a system (kernel) virtual address, not a process virtual address.

Comment: In other words, the memory allocated by `kmalloc()` doesn't belong to the task that allocated it. It belongs to the kernel. It is up to the kernel code to use the allocated memory how it sees fit.